WPF UI does not update when the Binding value is changed twice within the same method call
I have an WPF screen with 2 labels: busy and ready.
When I run an update within a method call (RunProcess), triggered with a button, I want to change the visibility at the start to show the busy label and hide the ready label, and show ready + hide busy at the end of the process which can take a few minutes to run.
I defined the Binding in my XAML
<Label Name="Busy" Content="Busy" Visibility="{Binding Path=BusyVisibility, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<Label Name="Ready" Content="Busy" Visibility="{Binding Path=ReadyVisibility, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

XAML INotifyPropertyChanged class:
public class Status : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Status()
    {
        _readyVisibility = true;
        _busyVisibility = false;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public Visibility ReadyVisibility
    {
        get { return _readyVisibility; }
        set
        {
            _readyVisibility = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ReadyVisibility");
        }
    }
    private Visibility _readyVisibility;

     public Visibility BusyVisibility
    {
        get { return _busyVisibility; }
        set
        {
            _busyVisibility= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("BusyVisibility");
        }
    }
    private Visibility _busyVisibility;
}

and my screen XAML class:
public partial class MainWindow : UserControl
{
    private ScreenStatusVisibility _screenStatusVisibility = new ScreenStatusVisibility();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _screenStatusVisibility;
    }
    
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReadyVisibility = false;
        BusyVisibility = true;
        //processing ..
        ReadyVisibility = true;
        BusyVisibility = false;
    }
}

When I click on the button, the Busy label is never hidden, even when I put a sleep or debug step by step. It seems that WPF doesn't update the UI within a single method call.

You don't have a BusyVisibility property so your Busy label's binding will never work.

you are blocking UI thread ... UI cannot update state when is blocked... so the change is done after you unblock (exit Button_Click)

The class you "documented" is not the same as the DataContext. The properties in Button_Click are "undefined". This cannot compile as presented.

Thanks for your replies. I added the BusyVisibility in the example. I agree with  @Selvin and I will look at the answer below

Just move processing to task.run and await it

Of course you cannot update ui directly from task

@Selvin thx for more fine comments! My example would have been clearer if I had put await Task.Run(()=>{...}) as the processing simulation instead of await Task.Delay(...). Con permiso, I'd like to make that improvement based on your input.

Fun fact: with task.deley before processing it "would work" but still it would block ui when processing... As button click will end after task.deley and then rest of the code would executed back on ui thread after delay

I hope that op didn't use this solution

Unclear. Are we in agreement that the click handler returns immediately upon encountering the first await thereby "not blocking" the UI thread? That the Thread.Sleep occurs on a background thread, and that the default resume context of await here would be .ConfigureAwait(true) and so when the Task continues on DataContext.Status.ReadyVisibility = Visibility.Visible it's still in the UI synchronization context? If you are running my sample and find a way to break it, please let me know. I would always want to promptly correct or remove an answer that has a proven issue.

Oh! I think I get what you're saying and (if so) I agree! Ok, so before when I used TaskDelay, it was intended in and of itself to represent or simulate a long running task, to be the work, and that's the part that wasn't clear then that I hope is clearer now. There's no problem here, folks.

What should help your problem is to make the click handler async and await your processing task. The excellent comment added by Selvin articulates the underlying issue of blocking the UI thread. Making the handler async fixes that. For example, you could disable the Test button, hide Ready, show Busy, run the work with a progress update on the UI thread, then reverse the status indicators.
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext.Status.ReadyVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    var progress = new Progress<int>(percent =>
    {
        progressBar.Value = percent;
    });
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Simulate a 2 S background processing task.
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            ((IProgress<int>)progress).Report(i * 5);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    });

    DataContext.Status.ReadyVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
}



Another possible point of failure is bindings that aren't bound to the intended models. If this is the case, it still won't work in spite of changing the click handler. So, out of an abundance of caution, here's the full code I used to test this answer.
Xaml
<Window x:Class="wpf_change_value_two_times.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_change_value_two_times"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="500">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
        <Style x:Key="CenteredContentStyle" TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Label 
                Style="{StaticResource CenteredContentStyle}"
                Content="Ready" 
                Visibility="{Binding Status.ReadyVisibility}"
                Background="Green"
                Foreground="White" />
            <Label
                Style="{StaticResource CenteredContentStyle}"
                Content="Busy"
                Visibility="{Binding Status.BusyVisibility}"  
                Grid.Column="0"
                Background="LightSalmon"
                Foreground="Yellow"  />
        </Grid>

        <Button 
            Style="{StaticResource CenteredContentStyle}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Status.IsButtonEnabled}" 
            Content="Test"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Click="Button_Click"/>

        <ProgressBar 
            x:Name="progressBar" 
            Grid.Row="2"
            Minimum="0" 
            Maximum="100" 
            Height="20"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>


C#
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace wpf_change_value_two_times
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow() => InitializeComponent();
        new MainWindowViewModel DataContext => (MainWindowViewModel)base.DataContext;

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext.Status.ReadyVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            var progress = new Progress<int>(percent =>
            {
                progressBar.Value = percent;
            });
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // Simulate a 2 S background processing task.
                for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
                {
                    ((IProgress<int>)progress).Report(i * 5);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            });

            DataContext.Status.ReadyVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

Main view model
    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public Status Status { get; set; } = new Status();
    }
    

Status subclass
    public class Status : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Visibility ReadyVisibility
        {
            get => _readyVisibility;
            set
            {
                if (!Equals(_readyVisibility, value))
                {
                    _readyVisibility = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BusyVisibility));
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsButtonEnabled));
                }
            }
        }
        Visibility _readyVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

        public Visibility BusyVisibility => 
            Equals(ReadyVisibility, Visibility.Visible) ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;

        public bool IsButtonEnabled => 
            Equals(ReadyVisibility, Visibility.Visible);

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null) =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    }
}


Clone

Thanks @IV , I confirm that it works from initial tests. I have yet to integrate it in the project where the Ready/Busy label are within a reusable Header XAML Screen. Hopefully it'll still work.

I managed to get the labels from the shared header XAML screen to update via the DataContext property. Integrated it with a first screen, it worked but I have some comments. I'm not sure if there's room to improvements:

Maybe it's a new question though? It sounds like you fixed the main problem with change twice within the same method call...? Best to answer "one question on one thread".

-> In the await Task.Run(()... I initially called a RunProcess method that I wanted to run as a separate thread (so I could cancel it) but I ended moving the content of this method here. It works except I had to move some code that updated my TreeViewItems outside the Task.Run as I got an exception about locked elements within a different thread.

OK, so a couple of things. 1. you can pass CancellationToken to Task.Run() for this purpose. 2. anything you do in the background thread that affect the UI thread needs to be marshaled onto the UI thread using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. But the big thing might be...

3. if you find yourself invoking a lot from your background thread, maybe it isn't really background work at all because you have just the one UI thread. In other words, we don't want to incur a bunch of extra overhead marshaling between threads for something that we're going to take a hit for on the UI thread anyway. Anyway, good luck and check out all the SO posts on the subject or, if you have to, make a new question describing this tree scenario better.

Thank you for your feedback. I will check the existing questions or raise a new one should I can't sort the collateral issue. The initial topic has been resolved with your help
